# $|x_n| \to \infty \implies |f(x_n)| \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function.
>
> Show that
>
> 1) $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} |f(x)|=\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty}|f(x)|=+\infty$
>
> implies
>
> 2) $|x_n|\to \infty \implies |f(x_n)|\to \infty$.

I know that $f$ is continuous iff $x_n \to a \implies f(x_n)\to f(a)$.

But, can I use

$\lim|f(x_n)|= |f(\lim(x_n))|=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} |f(x)|=+\infty$

for infinite cases so directly?

If the solution is not this way, could you help me by giving a hint how to do it?

Comment: Do you know the definition of 1?

Comment: For all $A\in\mathbb{R}$ exists $\delta>0$ such that $x>\delta \implies |f(x)|>A$ ($+\infty$ case)?

Comment: Yes you need to use this definition. The one you stated is about continuity at a fixed point but infinity is not a point.

Comment: $|x_n|\to \infty$ means 

$$\forall M, \exists \overline{n} \in \mathbb{N} : n>\overline{n} \implies |x_n|>M$$.

So, since that $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ (domain of $f$), 

$$\forall M \quad \exists \bar x : \forall x_n\, |x_n|>\bar x \quad |f(x_n)|>M$$

so

$$\forall M, \exists \overline{n} \in \mathbb{N} : n>\overline{n} \implies |f(x_n)|>M$$.

that's it?

Comment: Continuity is not needed for this.

Comment: It;s not true unless you change |$x_n|$ to $x_n$ in 2).

Comment: The problema have one more item where, I believe, continuity is necessary.
3) If $K$ is compact, then $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first condition means

$$\forall M \quad \exists \bar x : \forall x\, |x|>\bar x \quad |f(x)|>M$$

and from here the second follows, indeed we have

$$\forall \bar x \quad \exists \bar n : \forall n>\bar n \quad |x_n|> \bar x$$

that is

$$\forall M \quad \exists \bar n : \forall n>\bar n \quad |f(x_n)|>M$$

Comment: $|x_n|\to \infty$ means 

$$\forall M, \exists \overline{n} \in \mathbb{N} : n>\overline{n} \implies |x_n|>M$$.

So, since that $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ (domain of $f$), 

$$\forall M \quad \exists \bar x : \forall x_n\, |x_n|>\bar x \quad |f(x_n)|>M$$

so

$$\forall M, \exists \overline{n} \in \mathbb{N} : n>\overline{n} \implies |f(x_n)|>M$$.

that's it?

Comment: Sorry for massive edits ._.

Comment: If you use the same M it is not much clear. For the first line just assume $M=\bar x$ in that way we know that exists $\bar n$ such that $\forall n>\bar n \quad |x_n|>\bar x$.